# SEO friendly URL in php

Tags: php, seo

I am working on a wordpress site.

This is mt site URL:

```
http://mybridalpix.staging.wpengine.com/?p_action=user_profile&post_author=2286&city=jaipur&state=rajasthan
```

I want this URL like:

```
http://mybridalpix.staging.wpengine.com/?user_profile&2286&city=jaipur&state=rajasthan
```

How can do it by editing the .htaccess file or something else way?

Comment: Have you looked at mod_rewrite?  It would convert the URL you want to the URL you have, but you will also have to change all the links on your site so search engines pick it up.  The author number might be problematic.

Answer (score -1):

You need to rewrite your url in .htaccess, here u have a link. https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/